# $3$ points are collinear

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, solution-verification, triangles

$M$ is a point on $AB$. $BMC$ and $AMD$ are constructed such that they are both equilateral & on the same side of $AB$. The circumcircle of both triangle intersect at $M$ and $N$. Prove that $AD$ and $BC$ intersects at $N$.

Can anyone verify my solution:

It's enough to show $A,N,D$ collinear or $\angle ANB+\angle BND=\pi$. But $\angle ANB=\angle ANM+\angle MNB = \pi/3 + \pi/3 = 2\pi /3$ (because they are facing the same arc). Similarly it's easy to see that $\angle BND = \pi/3$. We are done.

Comment: $\angle ANB=2\pi/3$. You need to say that  B, N, C are collinear as well.

Comment: In the question, do you want triangle $BMD$ instead? Can you add a diagram?

Comment: @CalvinLin I think that's correct. This is one of the problems on EGMO chapter 2 if I am not mistaken.

Comment: $\pi/3+\pi/3=\pi/6???$

Comment: Ok, I fixed it all. I was in a hurry then.

Comment: @torontohrb Other than that, is it correct?

Comment: I think it is correct. If B, N, C are also collinear, $AD$ and $BC$ intersect at N.